# Working out length of taut rope orbiting the earth remaining straight and radially directed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gravity, orbital-motion

A taut rope is orbiting the earth with angular velocity $a$. It remains straight and radially directed. If the midpoint is located at radius $r$, find the length of the rope.

I can't even imagine where to start with this problem, how does it become radially directed?

Comment: $2r$ ? Isn't that the definition of midpoint?

Comment: No, it doesn't necessarily reach the centre of the earth

Comment: The problem doesn't ask you how the rope remains radially directed, so just assume it.  Every point on the rope segment has the same angular velocity as the midpoint.  r is the distance from the center of the Earth to the midpoint of the rope segment.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

If the rope is "radially directed" it means every point has the same angular velocity $\omega$. Assume a length $2\ell$, then you can integrate the force on the rope from $r-\ell$ to $r+\ell$ - gravitational force must equal centripetal force.

This gives you an equation for $\ell$ as a function of $\omega$ and $r$.

See if that gets you going.